# Android: startActivity which goes to another Activity with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Let's say I have activity A which is going to start Activity B upon the click of a button:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Now, Activity B is an Activity that has a tablayout and clicking on the tabs will change the pages in the viewpager on that activity. Each page on the viewpager displays a fragment.

There are 3 tabs in Activity B. I started Activity A by going to the 3rd tab and clicking on a button there.

When I click the button on Activity A, it allows me to go back to activity B but it goes straight to the first tab.

How can I make it go to the 3rd tab when it returns from Activity A?

Comment: You can pass the number of the last tab across the intent with intent.putExtras() and use then in activity B with viewPager.setCurrentItem(numTab);

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

If I just call finish() in Activity A without using the intent to move from A to B, I land back in Activity B in the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

When you start `ActivityB` from for the second time that you want to go to 3rd tab the start activity like this

```
 startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityB.class).putExtra("go_to", 3));
```

`onCreate` method in `ActivityB` after initializing the `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` use this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int position = bundle.getInt("go_to");
            if (position != -1) {
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
            }
        }
```

this will take to the 3rd tab